# Get a burger menu accessible from all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm newbie with CSS and would go with the beautifull CSS burger menu from Victor Frere : http://codepen.io/victorfreire/pen/QywRNM

My main page content will replace the following example text :

```
#1 Burger Menu
inspired by
Google Material Design
```

How could have the 3 bars menu visible and accessible on all pages of the website ?

i mean, if user clicks on the burgermenu, click on 'About' link , that wpage loads but so far the burger menu no longer visible on the top left hand side ?

What modifications should i do to get the burger menu always accessible from any page ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well either you could use php [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp), or you could simply copy and paste the burger menu html code into all pages, maybe I understood you wrong but from what I understand this should work, let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I would like to set the burger menu into a div, that div would be called from links pages of the site in order to display it at a specified location.  should i make a menu.php that would include the following : `<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"/>
  <label id="trigger" for="menu-toggle"></label>
  <label id="burger" for="menu-toggle"></label>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>`

Comment: Yeah that is something you could do, and then in each file do:

<?php include "menu.php"; ?>